# USING client ip address while using PHP CURL to post form data

Tags: php, forms, curl, ip

I am trying to use curl to post data to a form and everything works very well except that when I send the form, it makes use of the server ip address in sending the form but what I really would like to do is to set a custom user agent(The reason why I need to use curl) and I need the client's ip to remain intact.

Here is the code I am using right now.

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//The next line set the user agent to a custom one.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mobile UA :" . $rrand );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I want curl to use the client ip address while sending the form and not the address of the server hosting the php script. If it is possible to set custom server address to post the form, that would help as well.

Comment: and what legitimate reason could you have for IP spoofing?

Comment: you would want to use a `jsonp` request from the users browser to do what your looking to do

Comment: @cmorrissey — You can't specify the user-agent a browser will send for a JSONP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were able to forge the request so it looked like it came from the user's network, then the response would also go to the user's network where nothing would be waiting for it.

So no, it is not possible.

Comment: I do not need to receive the response as long as the data was sent successfully.